# Populate WTForms form from dictionary when using Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask-WTF form that needs to be populated from a dictionary, which I pass in as `**kwargs`.  The form is used in a Flask route that is accessed using the `POST` method.  The form doesn't validate, and the field's value is `None`.  How can I pass a dictionary of data to my form and then validate it?

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    data = {'name': 'eee'}
    form = MyForm(**data)
    print(form.validate())  # False, name is required
    print(form.name.data)  # None
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flask-WTF [automatically](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/v0.12/flask_wtf/form.py#L72) passes `request.form` when the route is posted to, if no data is passed explicitly.  You need to pass your data, as a [`MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), to prevent the automatic behavior.  Passing `obj`, `data`, or `**kwargs`, only sets the defaults, which are [only used](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/faq.html#why-does-blank-input-not-go-back-to-the-default-value) if no real data is passed to the form.

```
form = MyForm(MultiDict(data))
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use **data** parameter for the constructor. You can also check the [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html)

```
  form = MyForm(data=data)
```

Comment: I've tried data= and didn't work. 'name' was never set.